# how to do dual circular slider (clock like function)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uislider

i will like to know how to do a dual slider in the attached image.

i am looking at this codes to modified it. i will like to know how to have 2 slider to allow user to choose the desired time.

The problem i encounter are how do i have 2 slider to show something like the image?

http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/tb_circularslider

any comment are greatly appreciated here.

[image]

Comment: Your question consists of many different subquestions and to be honest I would almost like to close it as "Not a real question" since that makes it so hard to answer but I want to try and help. What have you tried and what is the biggest problem you are encountering? Do you know how to make a flat slider with two thumbs? Is it the circular drawing that is holding you back? etc. Also, your question does not give enough detail for how the slider should work for someone to fully answer it. You say "clock like". Is it a range of hours or a minute-hour selection (i.e. one hand affecting the other)?

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist thanks for the reply.
I am learning how with references with http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/bjrangesliderwithprogress

Yes is the circular drawing that is holding me back.

is the range of hours that i'm looking for, that allow user to start from 6pm to 10pm (4 hours).

i'm sorry for the confusing question.

Comment: So is it the circular _drawing_ or the circular _touch handling_ that is confusing you? I had a quick glance at [the accompanying blog post](http://www.thinkandbuild.it/how-to-build-a-custom-control-in-ios/) and it seems to explain both quite well.

Comment: @Desmond it would be kinda nice if you tell me if this is what you are looking for

Comment: @relikd sorry for the late reply. was away for some personal matter last week i gonna try it out if it work now. will keep u updated... thanks for sharing the code... cheers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

for the dual slider positions you have this excerpt in code

```
CGContextAddArc(imageCtx, self.frame.size.width/2  , self.frame.size.height/2, radius, 0, ToRad(self.angle), 0);
```

the first zero (`0`) is the starting point, so you want to use a different angle here

```
CGContextAddArc(imageCtx, self.frame.size.width/2  , self.frame.size.height/2, radius, ToRad(self.startAngle), ToRad(self.endAngle), 0);
```

(you need those two ivar's in your header of course)

EDIT: here is the edited code to find the nearest knob and lock it for modification. The old code didn't locked it, so it would change upon hover from one knob to another.
First of all add the `enum` above your implementation:

```
enum SliderLockType {
    SliderLockedNone = 0,
    SliderLockedStart,
    SliderLockedEnd
};

#pragma mark - Implementation -

@implementation TBCircularSlider
enum SliderLockType sliderLock;

// … some code here …
   //Initialize the Angle at 0
   //self.startAngle = 0;
   //self.endAngle = 270;

/** Tracking is started **/
-(BOOL)beginTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [super beginTrackingWithTouch:touch withEvent:event];

    // find nearest knob …
    CGPoint lastPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
    CGPoint pStart = [self centerPointFromAngel:self.startAngle];
    CGPoint pEnd   = [self centerPointFromAngel:self.endAngle];
    float diffA = [self distanceBetween:lastPoint and:pStart];
    float diffB = [self distanceBetween:lastPoint and:pEnd];

    // … and lock it
    if (diffA <= TB_LINE_WIDTH) { // the tolerance is the width of the circle
        sliderLock = SliderLockedStart;
    } else if (diffB <= TB_LINE_WIDTH) {
        sliderLock = SliderLockedEnd;
    }

    //We need to track continuously
    return YES;
}

// continueTrackingWithTouch:withEvent: stays unchanged

/** Track is finished **/
-(void)endTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [super endTrackingWithTouch:touch withEvent:event];

    // reset the lock before starting a new touch event
    sliderLock = SliderLockedNone;
}

- (CGPoint)centerPointFromAngel:(int)angleInt {
    CGPoint point = [self pointFromAngle:angleInt];
    point.x += TB_LINE_WIDTH/2;
    point.y += TB_LINE_WIDTH/2;
    return point;
}

- (CGFloat)distanceBetween:(CGPoint)p1 and:(CGPoint)p2 {
    CGFloat xDist = (p2.x - p1.x);
    CGFloat yDist = (p2.y - p1.y);
    return sqrt((xDist * xDist) + (yDist * yDist));
}

// … some more code …

- (void)drawTheHandle:(CGContextRef)ctx {

    CGContextSaveGState(ctx);

    //I Love shadows
    CGContextSetShadowWithColor(ctx, CGSizeMake(0, 0), 3, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);

    //Get the handle position!
    CGPoint handleCenterA =  [self pointFromAngle: self.startAngle];
    CGPoint handleCenterB =  [self pointFromAngle: self.endAngle];

    //Draw It!
    [[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.7]set];
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, CGRectMake(handleCenterA.x, handleCenterA.y, TB_LINE_WIDTH, TB_LINE_WIDTH));
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, CGRectMake(handleCenterB.x, handleCenterB.y, TB_LINE_WIDTH, TB_LINE_WIDTH));

    CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
}

- (void)movehandle:(CGPoint)lastPoint {

    //Get the center
    CGPoint centerPoint = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2);

    //Calculate the direction from the center point to an arbitrary position.
    float currentAngle = AngleFromNorth(centerPoint, lastPoint, NO);
    int angleInt = 360 - floor(currentAngle);

    if (sliderLock == SliderLockedStart) {
        self.startAngle = angleInt;
    } else if (sliderLock == SliderLockedEnd) {
        self.endAngle = angleInt;
    }

    //Redraw
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

the result:
[image: modified TBCircularSlider Lib]

EDIT2: if you like to have the slider switching from hour to hour you can modify the `movehandle:` method as follows:

```
int angleInt = (int)(360 - floor(currentAngle)) / 30 * 30; // 360/30 = 12 -> hours

if (sliderLock == SliderLockedStart && angleInt%360 != self.endAngle%360) {
    self.startAngle = angleInt;
} else if (sliderLock == SliderLockedEnd && angleInt%360 != self.startAngle%360) {
    self.endAngle = angleInt;
}
```

Comment: thanks for this awesome code!!, it works like charm. Will you be able to help me out one more time on the collision detection as i do not want each other to overlap. also do you know how to change the touch on the 2 white knob only ?

your reply are greatly appreciated!!!

des

Comment: edited the code, I think this is exactly what you want. The slider will jump into the 12 hour places like on a clock. Plus added some knob locking to prevent editing the second knob while moving the first

Comment: thanks this is what i need. really appreciated your help.
do i need to do something in -(BOOL)continueTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event ??

as if i continue touching the knot will over flow it.